# iOS: Firebase phone Authenication

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I develop an iOS app that use firebase phone authentication, I follow google  documentation, but I always have the following error:

```
If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's canHandleNotificaton: method.
```

and My appDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
    {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication , didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
    {
        if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification)
        {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData);
            return
        }
    }
```

So how can I resolve that?

Comment: Your answer is good, but you should use - FirebaseApp.configure(options: options) -, where options will be path to your google plist file (let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath)!).

Answer (score 4):

If swizzling is disabled, you need to do two things for phone number auth to work:

Set APNSToken on the FIRAuth instance with your APNs token. This is independent of setting APNs token for FCM (using the FCM client SDK is not required for using phone number auth).
Call **canHandleNotification** on the FIRAuth instance with the remote notification you received from the **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler**: method on your UIApplicationDelegate instance. This is also independent of notifying FCM. [It's documented in under section "Receive notifications without swizzling"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#appendix:-using-phone-sign-in-without-swizzling).

Comment: If U saw I implement that.